# view detail in new page when click on button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display the clicked row button details info in next view,I am displayin only code,nom in first page and remaining fields will view after clicking button. I used the option "filter" to do it, but sometimes it returns details of non concerned code , like for the two codes: 45 and 453 , it gaves the same detail because of the common number '45'.

First html page:

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="SuiviAdminCtrl" ng-init="load()">
<div class="row header">

          <div class="col" >Code</div>
          <div class="col">Client</div>        
</div>

<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in namesC">
          <div class="coll"> 
             <a class="button" href="#/detail/{{x.Code}}">
             {{x.Code}}</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="col"> {{x.NomClient}}  </div>              
</div>
```

second html page (detail.html):

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="x in namesC| filter: {Code: thisX}|limitTo:1"> 

          <ion-item> 
          <div class="item item-divider center-text"> {{x.Code}}</div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
          <b>adresse</b> <span class="item-note">  {{x.adresse}} </span>
          </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the filter, so that it could match the code strictly.

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="x in namesC| filter: {Code: thisX}: strict|limitTo:1">
```

alternate syntax:

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="x in namesC| filter: {Code: thisX}: false|limitTo:1">
```

If you look at syntax of filter, you can specify filter. The default value of filter if `false`, which means comparison would not be strict.

[fitler in angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: I did it, but I still have the same confusion , the two code 45 and 456 returns the same details